# WCF Service when publishing creates a svc file with namespace. How to avoid the Namespace

Tags: wcf, namespaces

I do not have any problems with running the WCF service and consuming it using the client.
I created a WCF service with a Namespace namespace1.

When I try to publish the service from the build menu, it creates a file called namespace1.servicename.svc

Is there a way I can create a servicename.svc without the namespace in it

[Edit]
The publish.xml file shows the reURL as "namespace.servericename.svc" how do i change the publish to not show the namespace.

Thanks,

Comment: Is your WCF service a WCF Service Library (DLL)?

Comment: My WCF service is a service not a service library(DLL)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a "WCF Service Application", you won't have this issue.  The project will generate a .svc file for your project instead of creating one when publishing.